# UIPageViewController does not show its content view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I can't seem to get a UIPageViewController working. With the code below, the PageViewController calls all of its data source methods and even shows the corresponding dots, but the actual content views are not displayed (even though I checked in debug that the view controllers are instantiated correctly). Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: the view controller is not nil, but all its properties are. Apparently there is something going wrong with the instantiation.

```
//content view controller containing a text label
#import "TutorialPhoneContentViewController.h"

@interface TutorialRootViewController ()

@end

@implementation TutorialRootViewController {
    NSInteger numberOfViewControllers;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    numberOfViewControllers = 3;

    [self setUpViewControllers];
}

- (void)setUpViewControllers {
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;


    TutorialPhoneContentViewController *ctrl = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[ctrl] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self.pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (TutorialPhoneContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    //this returns the correct view controller, checked via debug

    TutorialPhoneContentViewController *ctrl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tutorialContentViewController"];
    ctrl.index = index;
    ctrl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"View Controller #%ld", index];

    return ctrl;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [(TutorialPhoneContentViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger index = [(TutorialPhoneContentViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == numberOfViewControllers-1) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return numberOfViewControllers;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The usual pattern is to have your view controller as a subclass of UIPageViewController, though I suppose you have a good reason to use a child view controller here. Did you position the UIPageViewController's view and/or set constraints on it?

Comment: Just resolved it. Your tip with the subcalssing did it. TutorialPhoneContentViewController was a subclass of UIPageViewController. Making it a subclass of UIViewController got it working: @interface TutorialPhoneContentViewController : UIViewController